# Template is not overriding after the default installation of tomcat7

Tags: ansible

I have simple ansible role that do following tasks:

1. Install tomcat7
2. Update the /etc/default/tomcat7 - this is for configuring heap and other configuration
3. Update /etc/tomcat7/server.xml - this will override the tomcat port from 8080 to 80
4. restart the tomcat service

This is how my role looks like:

```
- name: Update apt cache
  apt: update_cache=yes

- name: Install Tomcat 7
  apt: pkg=tomcat7 state=present

- name: Configure tomcat memory/java_home configuration
  template: src=tomcat7.j2 dest=/etc/default

- name: Configure tomcat server configuration, port, connections ssl etc
  template: src=server.xml.j2 dest=/etc/tomcat7

 notify: 
- tomcat7-restart
```

This file stored in roles/task and my template in roles/template

When i run the playbook, I dont see any error or warning, but when go and check the actual file its not updated, showing the default content that comes with the tomcat7 installation.

Please let me know if you guys have any idea what I am doing wrong here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `dest` parameter in the template task should be the full path to the file, not just a directory path.  You will want to change your tasks to look something like this:

Edit: And the right way to use the "notify" command is to include that in each task as well.  That way if either task modifies its associated file then the handler to restart tomcat will be called, but if neither file is modified then tomcat won't be restarted.

```
- name: Configure tomcat memory/java_home configuration
  template: src=tomcat7.j2 dest=/etc/default/tomcat7
  notify: tomcat7-restart

- name: Configure tomcat server configuration, port, connections ssl etc
  template: src=server.xml.j2 dest=/etc/tomcat7/server.xml
  notify: tomcat7-restart
```

You will also want your roles/tomcat7/handlers/main.yml file to look something like this:

```
---
- name: tomcat7-restart
  service: name=tomcat7 state=restarted
```